# Match d-M-Y with javascript regex how?

Tags: javascript, regex

my date formatting in PHP is d-M-Y and I'm trying to match the dates with a javascript regex:

```
s.match(new RegExp(/^(\d{1,2})(\-)(\w{3})(\-)(\d{4})$/))
```

To be used with the jQuery plugin, tablesorter. The problem is it's not working and I'm wondering why not.

I tried removing the dashes in my date() formatting (d M Y) and tried the ff and it worked:

```
s.match(new RegExp(/^\d{1,2}[ ]\w{3}[ ]\d{4}$/));
```

My question is what is the correct regex if I'm using dashes on PHP's date() i.e. d-M-Y? Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need to create a `RegExp` object. You can use `s.match(/pattern/)`. I don't have time to help with the problem, but that jumped out at me!

Comment: are you trying to construct a Javascript date object or just break the PHP string into date, month, and year?

Comment: I'm trying to break the PHP string into date month and year

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace it with either

```
s.match(new RegExp("^(\\d{1,2})(\\-)(\\w{3})(\\-)(\\d{4})$"));
```

or

```
s.match(/^(\d{1,2})(\-)(\w{3})(\-)(\d{4})$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually more tolerant when matching dates, so I'd do something like this:

```
s.match( /^\s*(\d{1,2})\W+(\w{3})\W+(\d{4})\s*$/ )
```

(tolerate leading and trailing whitespace and any non-alphanumeric chars a s delimiters)